# Could not run VS Code on CentOS 7 with x2go

Tags: centos, visual-studio-code, centos7

I have installed the latest version of VS Code on CentOS 7.
However when I try to run VS Code, it loads for some time trying to open, but then nothing happens, no errors, nothing.
I have tried to installed both trough rpm package and zipped files, but got the same result in both cases.

I'm using x2go to connect to my CentOS 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following line to the file **/etc/x2go/x2goagent.options**:

> X2GO_NXAGENT_DEFAULT_OPTIONS+=" -extension BIG-REQUESTS"

Then restart the server and try again.

I had the same problem and added the **--verbose** flag to get more info (see below). Googling for the "gl_surface_glx.cc" error brought me to https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4360 which contains the above workaround. VS Code now works for me on CentOS7 with X2GO.

Without this workaround the following error is seen (using the --verbose flag):

> $ code --user-data-dir=/home/user1646217
>   --verbose [19526:0719/091952.335817:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(317)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
>   [19526:0719/091952.335923:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(278)] Multiple
>   instances of AudioManager detected
>   [19549:0719/091952.363736:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(411)] GLX 1.3 or
>   later is required.
>   [19549:0719/091952.363836:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(130)]
>   GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
>   [19549:0719/091952.366430:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(327)] Exiting GPU
>   process due to errors during initialization

Comment: It turned out, that this is a know issue for VS code https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25611

Comment: So happy you answer helped me. Thanks a ton.